# Excel Drop down list of formulas or vba functions that will do the same

Tags: excel, vba

Can I have a drop-down list where I choose which formula to use
I have a series of formulas i.e `=indirect(address(row(),4)))*deposit` where a deposit is a named range and I want to be able to pick which formula to use basically the only part of the formula that will change is the named range

I cant just enter a formula into data validation.
I am also ok if it's possible to duplicate the formula into a custom vba function but not sure how to do this

basically, I need to be able to take a dollar value from a cell that is relative to the current cell and times it by a percentage that is in one of the named ranges

Comment: Can you use an extra column with the Named Range name in a drop down, e.g. Named Range drop-down in `Z1` with the formula in `AA1` then write `=$D1 * INDIRECT($Z1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrote this a while back for a different purpose, modified and added some comments.

Place in ThisWorkbook & trigger the macro by typing(without quotes) "_" in any cell except in column 4 (D:D) and then press Enter.

Also your named ranges should end with a  "_ " (eg "deposit_") this is due to the condition of the second Case and is necessary to avoid triggering when editing a descriptive cell of text.

Typing "-" and pressing Enter removes the validation and value.

```
Public Str As String

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If ActiveSheet.Index = 1 Then 'If you want to limit the reach of this
    With Target
        If .Count = 1 Then 'Limits to single cell to avoid errors
            If .Column <> 4 Then 'So that it can't refer to itself unless you try in one of them named ranges
                Select Case True
                    Case (.Value Like "_") 'Triggers if cell value equals "_"
                        For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names 'Adds all names to a string
                            Str = Str & "," & nm.Name
                        Next nm
                        .Validation.Delete 'Removes previous validation
                        .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=Replace(Str, ",", "", 1, 1) 'Adds the list of names to validation
                        .Validation.ShowError = False 'Makes it possible edit without removing validation
                        .Select: SendKeys ("%{UP}") 'Triggers the dropdown list

                    Case (.Value Like "*_") 'Triggers if cell value ends with "_"
                        .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC4*" & .Value 'Applies formula

                    Case (.Value Like "-") 'Triggers if cell value equals "-"
                        .Validation.Delete 'Removes validation from cell
                        .Value = "" 'Removes value

                End Select
                Str = "" 'Empties out string
            End If
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance to dissect your code as yet, ill let you know once i have had a look at it